# MBean Registration with same(Single) object name for multiple objects of same class

Tags: java, jmx, mbeans, objectname

Is there a way for MBean Registration with same(Single) object name for multiple objects of same class ? What is the simpler way ?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. If you try to register an instance which has the same name of another one that was already registered, a `javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException` will be thrown.

You have to use a different name for the second instance as follows:

```
MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();

ObjectName name = new ObjectName("firstInstance:type=Hello");
Hello mbean = new Hello();
mbs.registerMBean(mbean, name);

ObjectName name2 = new ObjectName("secondInstance:type=Hello");
Hello mbean2 = new Hello();
mbs.registerMBean(mbean2, name2);
```